# ipython works wrongs wrong with awk?

Tags: awk, ipython

Dear all！ I find a question with ipython.

When I input

```
!ls -l | awk '{print $$1}'
```

It gives me:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 ckivip ckivip  4096 Oct 11 20:38 Desktop

drwxr-xr-x  6 ckivip ckivip  4096 Oct 11 22:57 Documents

drwxrwxr-x  3 ckivip ckivip  4096 Oct 11 12:53 Downloads

drwxr-xr-x  6 ckivip ckivip  4096 Sep 29 18:22 Epigenetics

drwxr-xr-x  2 ckivip ckivip  4096 Sep 20 14:59 Music

drwxr-xr-x 23 ckivip ckivip  4096 Oct 10 11:02 Pictures

drwxr-xr-x  8 ckivip ckivip  4096 Sep 20 15:21 Project

drwx------  5 ckivip ckivip  4096 Sep 25 21:31 R

drwxr-xr-x  5 ckivip ckivip  4096 Oct  9 19:23 Share
```

However, when I input

```
!ls -l | awk '{print $1}'
```

It gives me:

```
drwxr-xr-x

drwxr-xr-x

drwxrwxr-x

drwxr-xr-x

drwxr-xr-x

drwxr-xr-x

drwxr-xr-x

drwx------
```

It's so annoying about the "$" symbol. And the most ugly thing is that I also can't transport the variables in python to shell using '$' when I use 'awk' function. How can I deal with it?

Comment: IPython lets you use `$var` to put Python variables into the command, so you have to double it up if you want to pass a literal `$` to the command. You can also use `{var}`, which might work in more cases.

Comment: In the first situation,I use double '$'. However, it gives me the wrong answer. In the second situation, I use only one '$'. And it gives me the right answer. Why? @Thomas K

Comment: Oh, because that whole bit is inside `{}` brackets (and it's not a valid Python expression), it gets passed through as is. So you don't need to double it up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with ipython but to address the part about passing the values of shell variables to awk: you do that with 'awk -v variable=value', so if you have a shell variable "$1" that contains the value "3" and you want awk to print the 3rd field of your input based on that, then the syntax is:

```
awk -v f="$1" '{ print $f }'
```

so in the above you could try:

```
!ls -l | awk -v f="$1" '{print $f}'
```

or if doubling the shell "$"s is required:

```
!ls -l | awk -v f="$$1" '{print $f}'
```

Hope that helps.